# dismiss ModalView Controller with UINavigation

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, push, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, dismiss

hey guys in my app there's a **parentViewController** and a **modalViewController**. i managed to display and dismiss the modal view using **storyboard** and class methods. but what i need is after dismissing the modal view, parent view should **push** to another **viewController**. is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `self` is a `parentViewController` (after dismissing the modal view):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```